# What' the meaning of the brackets in the class?

Tags: python

In python, when I read others' code, I meet this situation where a class is defined and after it there is a pair of brackets.

```
class AStarFoodSearchAgent(SearchAgent):
     def __init__():
        #....
```

I don't know what is the meaning of '(SearchAgent)',because what I usually meet and use doesn't seem that.

Comment: `()` == parenthesis `{}` ==  brackets `[]` == braces Just for future reference.

Comment: "Brackets" may be the British word for `()`, but in programming they are called parentheses to avoid confusion with `[]`.

Comment: @Takendarkk: At least where I'm from, `[]` are brackets and `{}` are braces.

Comment: Where I am from these are brackets `()` these are braces `{}` and these are square brackets `[]`.

Comment: Thanks for asking the right question the wrong way ... as how you put it is what I googled for ... now I know the right terminologies :-)

Comment: Throwing in another one (US, west coast): Parentheses (), square brackets/braces [], curly brackets/braces {}. To avoid confusion, they it's easiest to just always qualify them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It indicates that `AStarFoodSearchAgent` is a **subclass** of `SearchAgent`. It's part of a concept called **inheritance**.

## What is inheritance?

Here's an example. You might have a `Car` class, and a `RaceCar` class. When implementing the `RaceCar` class, you may find that it has a lot of behavior that is very similar, or exactly the same, as a `Car`. In that case, you'd make `RaceCar a subclass of`Car`.

```
class Car(object):
    #Car is a subclass of Python's base objeect. The reasons for this, and the reasons why you 
    #see some classes without (object) or any other class between brackets is beyond the scope 
    #of this answer.

    def get_number_of_wheels(self):
        return 4

    def get_engine(self):
        return CarEngine(fuel=30)

class RaceCar(Car):
#Racecar is a subclass of Car
    def get_engine(self):
        return RaceCarEngine(fuel=50)

my_car = Car() #create a new Car instance
desired_car = RaceCar() #create a new RaceCar instance.
my_car.get_engine() #returns a CarEngine instance
desired_car.get_engine() #returns a RaceCarEngine instance

my_car.get_number_of_wheels() #returns 4.
desired_car.get_number_of_wheels() # also returns 4! WHAT?!?!?!
```

We didn't define `get_number_of_wheels` on `RaceCar`, and still, it exists, and returns 4 when called. That's because `RaceCar` has inherited `get_number_of_wheels` from `Car`. Inheritance is a very nice way to reuse functionality from other classes, and override or add only the functionality that needs to be different.

## Your Example

In your example, `AStarFoodSearchAgent` is a subclass of `SearchAgent`. This means that it inherits some functionality from `SearchAgemt`. For instance, `SearchAgent` might implement a method called `get_neighbouring_locations()`, that returns all the locations reachable from the agent's current location. It's not necessary to reimplement this, just to make an A* agent.

What's also nice about this, is that you can use this when you expect a certain type of object, but you don't care about the implementation. For instance, a `find_food` function may expect a `SearchAgent` object, but it wouldn't care about how it searches. You might have an `AStarFoodSearchAgent` and a `DijkstraFoodSearchAgent`. As long as both of them inherit from `SearchAgent`, `find_food` can use ìsinstance`to check that the searcher it expects behaves like a`SearchAgent`. The`find_food`function might look like this:

```
def find_food(searcher):
    if not isinstance(searcher, SearchAgent):
        raise ValueError("searcher must be a SearchAgent instance.")

    food = searcher.find_food()
    if not food:
        raise Exception("No, food. We'll starve!")
    if food.type == "sprouts":
        raise Exception("Sprouts, Yuk!)
    return food
```

## Old/Classic Style Classes

Upto Python 2.1, old-style classes were the only type that existed. Unless they were a subclass of some other class, they wouldn't have any parenthesis after the class name.

```
class OldStyleCar:
    ...
```

New style classes always inherit from something. If you don't want to inherit from any other class, you inherit from `object`.

```
class NewStyleCar(object):
    ...
```

New style classes unify python types and classes. For instance, the type of `1`, which you can obtain by calling `type(1)` is `int`, but the type of `OldStyleClass()` is `instance`, with new style classes, `type(NewStyleCar)` is `Car`.

Answer (score 0):

`SearchAgent` is the superclass of the class `AStarFoodSearchAgent`. This basically means that an `AStarFoodSearchAgent` is a special kind of `SearchAgent`.

Answer (score 0):

It means that class **AStarFoodSearchAgent** extends **SearchAgent**.

Check section 9.5 here

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

This is inheritance in python, just like in any other OO language

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance

Answer (score 0):

It means that `SearchAgent` is a base class of `AStarFoodSearchAgent`. In other word, `AStarFoodSearchAgent` inherits from `SearchAgent` class.

See [Inheritance - Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).